# Converting an intranet site to internet

Tags: web-application

We currently have a web application with client sensitive data that is only accessible by the intranet.  The management wants to open this to the internet because there will be a need to have other companies to access this application.

- Has client sensitive data
- Only authorized person (inside or outside) can access it
- Account management is handled by IT only (i.e. no account creation by user, no "forget my password" mechanism)
- Current security measure: hashed password, SSL, no direct SQL statements used, database audit tables

I want to know if there is any guidelines that I should follow when assessing the risk.

Comment: Hashed how? What version of TLS?

Answer (score 2):

Very broad question, but here is a baseline of security additions I would add

1. Firewall rules to block ALL except authorized sources
2. Remote syslog/event logs
3. Web Application security test

This is beyond broad, and scattered. The reasoning? I have no idea what your risk is. Only you and your organization can determine that. So a quick risk analysis on a 50k view:

**Question**: *"I need to put this server online, what is the risk someone will get my data?"*

**Answer/Question**: Who has access to data (what network and why). Can I minimize this via a certificate, SSL, VPN, ACL?

**Answer/Question:** Once someone DOES access this site, what permissions do they have? Can they access all data, some data, how does it get processed, can someone attempt to access something they have permission for, if so will I know via logs, alerts?

**Answer/Question:** Can this be done safely over the Internet? Should I be introducing this risk not only to myself, but to my clients? Can I enable a VPN transaction, with this procedure documented so my clients understand I value their security?

Then there is the more granular problem outside of that server. "What if someone compromises this server, what can they do once on the server. Can they pivot back into the corporate network. Can they pivot unto any network in the routing tables? Can they sniff other client connections and compromise other clients?" This question is rather broad, and I hope I gave you some things to think about. There is no "what framework/standard/guideline" I can think of because 1) I don't know your industry 2) I don't know the purpose of your application 3) I don't know your organization's risk tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be accessed by other companies, I suggest to use the VPN. But if the VPN is not possible, please consider the following points

1. Tightened firewall allowing the traffic only through SSL
2. If possible permit only your client's IPs through the firewall
3. Make sure to run a full vulnerability testing on the site using softwares like OWASP ZAP or burpsuite
4. Make sure the Server OS components are up-to-date and all recent security patches installed
5. Make sure you are monitoring logs of the access and server.